# Algorithm for rdbms, select statement

Tags: sql, algorithm

hello dunno if this is the correct place to ask for this question,, im havin a thesis research and im in the algoritm now.. my thesis is an application that send messages using wherein the contacts will be query from the db.. so my question is what is the algorithm for searching the contacts from DB? linear search??

Comment: I'm having trouble following your question.  Can you use standard spelling, please.  And can you Start Sentences with Capital Letters?

Comment: Also, Smiley's won't attract good attention to your question.  Clarity, correct spelling and details help.  Smiley's hurt.

Answer (score 1):

If the `contacts` field is indexed in your database, it will be using `B-Tree` search, hash search or a `FULLTEXT` search (which is combination of some more simple algorithms), depending on the type of the index and the structure of the search query.

If the contacts are not indexed or a search query structure does not allow using an index, then yes, it will be using linear search.

Answer (score 0):

The index doesn't necessarily need to be primary index, it can be a index on any field. As Quassnoi said, you can specify the data structure beneath the index. Mysql assumes it to be B-tree by default. So the time to search the node will be O(logn) in case the tree is balanced, which B-tree are.

In case the contact field is not indexed, the db will linearly scan through each record and find the row until it finds one. This is worst case take O(n) time.